# Does there exist an infinite sequence of primes whose partial products (modulo some other prime) remain in a small set?

Tags: number-theory

For a given fixed prime $p$, I would like to know if there exists an infinite sequence of primes $(q)$, $p\neq q$, such that the sequence 
$$\prod_{q\leq Q}q \pmod p$$ remains in some small set as $Q\rightarrow\infty$, say of size $\delta p$ for some small $\delta$. I suspect not, although its not clear to me how technical this is. It seems difficult to formulate a proof and it is clearly not google friendly. Any suggestions would be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Certainly for $p=2, q\ne p$ the product is always $1 \bmod 2$. An analogous result is true for $p=3$, where $q\equiv \pm 1$.

Comment: What did you mean exactly with "an infinite sequence of primes" ? Dirichlet theorem says that given $p\nmid a$, for $Q$ large there are about $Q/(p-1)$ primes such that $q\le Q,q\equiv a\bmod p$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set of primes $ q \equiv 1 \mod p$. By Dirichlet's theorem there are infinitely many such primes, and the partial products mod $p$ are always $1$.